# Get coordinates during animation in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm doing some animation on a label like this:

```
lblNews1.Content = "OLA OLA OLA OLA";
lblNews1.Margin = new Thickness(0, altura - 50, 0, 0);
lblNews1.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
lblNews1.RenderTransform = trans;
DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(largura + 10, 0 - lblSize1.Width, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim1);
```

I wish to display the coordinates during this animation in some other control. Textbox or another label..

How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who needs it:

```
lblNews1.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX;
```